# get rank in marks database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Student database having one table EXAM.

```
id    1  2  3  4  5
marks 7 10  7 10  9
```

Question is how to give rank like

```
+------+
| rank |
+------+
|    3 |
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
```

I have used a Query:-

```
SELECT id, marks, FIND_IN_SET( marks, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( marks
ORDER BY marks DESC ) 
FROM exam )
) AS rank
FROM exam;
```

but it gives rank

```
+------+
| rank |
+------+
|    4 |
|    1 |
|    4 |
|    1 |
|    3 |
+------+
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 2):

Just add the word `DISTINCT` in front of the first `marks` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
SELECT id, marks, FIND_IN_SET( marks, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT marks
ORDER BY marks DESC ) 
FROM exam )
) AS rank
FROM exam;
```

First here is the sample data

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exam;
CREATE TABLE exam
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    marks int not null,
    primary key (id)
);
INSERT INTO exam (marks)
VALUES (7),(10),(7),(10),(9);
SELECT * FROM exam;
```

Let's load the sample data

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE exam
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     marks int not null,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO exam (marks)
    -> VALUES (7),(10),(7),(10),(9);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM exam;
+----+-------+
| id | marks |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     7 |
|  2 |    10 |
|  3 |     7 |
|  4 |    10 |
|  5 |     9 |
+----+-------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Now, watch the output of the proposed query:

```
mysql> SELECT id, marks, FIND_IN_SET( marks, (
    -> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT marks
    -> ORDER BY marks DESC )
    -> FROM exam )
    -> ) AS rank
    -> FROM exam;
+----+-------+------+
| id | marks | rank |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |     7 |    3 |
|  2 |    10 |    1 |
|  3 |     7 |    3 |
|  4 |    10 |    1 |
|  5 |     9 |    2 |
+----+-------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!